# SQL to find nearest location in one table from locations in another

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I have a table like this, that contains a few million locations (POINT):

```
CREATE TABLE NewLocations(
    [NewName] [varchar](20),
    [NewLocation] [geometry] 
)
```

I have another table like this, that contains a few hundred existing locations (POINT):

```
CREATE TABLE SourceData(
    [OriginalName] [varchar](20),
    [originalLocation] [geometry]
)
```

What I want to do is construct a sql select that for every row in SourceData find an entry(ies) in NewLocations that is within a few metres, in other words I'm trying to find a NewName either in the same place or near enough the same place as each originalname in SourceData.

e.g.

```
Name    NewName
loc1    loc56
loc2    NULL
```

I'm not bothered if there are multiple rows, I can remove them later, and there need not be a match.

With a single created point I can call STDistance and find a match, but I don't quite know how to construct the SQL for this to work with the table. I guess I could also turn it into a function, but I figured there might be a way to do it wholly in sql.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> construct a sql select that for every row in SourceData find an entry(ies) in NewLocations that is within a few metres

Something like:

```
select *
from NewLocations n
cross join SourceData s
where originalLocation.STDistance(NewLocation) < 5
```

Comment: Well, that was embarrassingly simple. I'll try it now. Is that the right way round? I want every row in SourceData with just matching rows in NewLocations. I guess it is, just seems not selecting from newlocations, or does it not matter given it's a cross join?